# Bootstrap and responsive images

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using .img-responsive class inside img tag. The image is quite small (42K) but when the page is loaded, the image shows multiple seconds as quite big until it shrinks to fit the size of the element holding it.

How should I deal with responsive elements with bootstrap?

Comment: Could you reproduce your issue in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Using `img-responsive` won't cause your image to do that, do you have some other code interfering?

Comment: Sounds like your CSS is taking a while to load

Comment: Sounds like what @JamesKing said without any code to see. If it's a big issue you could load the assets before displaying the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem happens when your library code (for example grid system) load late, and your 'IMG' tag probably has the following css:

**sass**

```
#yourIMG
     display:block
     max-width:100%
     height: auto
     width: 100% /*this one is your problem*/
```

and the `width:100%` make your `img` full width before your grid system load, you can either remove/overwrite that css or load your grid system code earlier

> Note: grid system , in here can be any file or `css` which control
>   your `img` parent tag `width`

Comment: @Aibrean **in SASS you can't use* `;` its a syntax error , i cant believe it you just edit my answer to add this

Comment: In a SCSS you definitely do use `;` and most Bootstrap uses LESS anyway.

Comment: i know but its a *SASS*

Comment: The problem turned out to be that there was a lot of css that got loaded before the grid system as was pointed out. I reduced unnecessary css and got rid of the problem.